# Cloud Files API with Indexable Meta Data

Tags: amazon-s3, google-drive-api, cloudfiles

I would like to use a cloud file system that supports adding meta-data that is searchable.  I want to use this meta-data to store keys from my application to associate the document.

E.g.

```
File:
/XYZ/image.png

Meta Data:
Person-Id:12345
Group-Id:23456
Other-Id:3456
```

I would then like to use a API to search (v.fast) documents by Person-Id or Group-Id.  I understand that I could create this table mapping myself (in mysql within the app) but is there a cloud files solution (google drive, rackspace, amazon) that supports this use case already?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the Directory API of Google to insert data onto the Google Drive which is hosted on cloud.

Send a POST request like this:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/groupKey/members
```

The require parameters include the *groupKey* which Identifies the group in the API request. The value can be the group's email address, group alias, or the unique group ID.

You can directly try this with this [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/insert).

For inserting a single member visit this [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert).